# Pointer to class field as lambda argument

Tags: c++

Why if we pass a class field pointer `int* value` in a lambda, then doesn't change `value`?

```
struct A {
  A() {
    auto f = [](int* value) {
      value = new int(0);
    };
    f(value);
  }

  int* value = new int(42);
};

int main()
{
  A obj{};
  std::cout << *(obj.value) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You modify pointer, not the pointee. You want: `*value = int(0)` ? .

Comment: oh, sorry. I want `value = new int(0)`

Comment: For the same reason that it wouldn't change if you used a "normal"  function. Assigning to a (non-reference) function parameter has no effect outside the function.

Comment: Then you need to take the pointer by reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes made to a function parameter are not visible to the caller, unless you take it by reference.

In your case, you would simply need to do

```
auto f = [](int* &value) {
   value = new int(0);
};
```

Now changes to the parameter `value` are reflected in the member `value`.

Note that in your example, (without the reference), the compiler would warn that you are setting `value` but not using it.

Also, this might solve the specific question, but you are still leaking memory here.

Answer (score 0):

your code isn't compilable - you cannot assign `int*` to `int` here: `value = int(0);`.
I have tried your code with fixed mentioned error:

```
struct A {
    A() {
        auto f = [](int* value) {
            *value = int(0);  // here value is being changed as expected
        };
        f(value);
    }

    int* value = new int(42);
};

int main()
{
    A obj{};
    std::cout << *(obj.value) << std::endl;
}
```

Everything works fine - passed `value` pointer to the `f` lambda is being changed from `42` to `0` value after constructor of struct is called.